# How to disable PDF editing in Preview app?

Tags: pdf, preview, macos

I am running OS X 10.10, Yosemite, and there is one *feature* which really annoys me. I know it must be useful for a lot of people but it's just not for me.

When I open a PDF document and, by habit, I keep clicking on the text while reading it. There are some areas where Preview thinks I would like to insert text.

[image: Preview screenshot]

As soon as this happens, the PDF document is marked *edited* in the title bar. When I close the document, it saves (or tries to save) it, changing the modify date and other side-effects such as triggering the DropBox sync etc.

I have accidentally inserted some text in many documents because Preview doesn't ask before saving the modified copy.

I would like to disable all PDF editing features unless explicitly invoked. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: This behaviour is already there in mavericks (the previous version of OSX) so it is not very much off-topic imho.

Comment: nominated for re-opening since this is still the behaviour in the now-released Yosemite (not to mention has been an existing issue in previous versions)

Comment: This is just so terribly annoying. My crafted page numbers completely disappear once it starts "editing".

Comment: Two years later, still the same problem... (on El Capitan) Do people at Apple use their own product?

Answer (score 18):

According to me, the best way to resolve this, is to go to System Preferences -> General.
Make sure "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" is selected.

[image: General preferences panel]

This will prevent accidental changes in PDF files, as well as other files when opened by other apps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: This option doesn't seem to be available on Preview 9.0 (909.12) on Sierra 10.12.2.

Comment: It works on Sierra 10.12.6. Don't know about earlier versions.

Comment: Works on El Capitan 10.11.6 -- thanks for posting!

Answer (score 16):

#### Rectangular Selection Tool

A pretty poor solution to this is change the selection mode from *Text Selection* to *Rectangular Selection* in the Tools menu.

[image: Tools menu: selection mode]

This stops you inserting random text fields, but also prevents you from selecting text, which may be equally annoying.

#### Locking the Document

If the document has been saved*, you can lock it...

* *(there is a state for temporary files, e.g. email attachments you've opened directly from the email in Apple's Mail.app, where they are aware they're a temporary file, so pressing Save opens up a Save As dialog, and you cannot lock the document)*

[image: Locked document]

However, while this prevents you from editing it, if you now click in one of those places that results in a new text field, you get a rather annoying pop-up dialogue asking if you want to unlock or duplicate the document:

[image: Locked document: unlock/duplicate dialogue]

So this too is not an ideal solution, because it interrupts you perhaps even more than the inadvertent-text-entry-box, but technically prevents you from editing it if the Dropbox sync or similar is the main concern.

#### Apple Feedback

I suspect there isn't a simple way of disabling/re-enabling the auto-form-filling features of Preview (which are amazing when you want them!), so would suggest you send [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) on this one.

Comment: feedback sent here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27046205

Comment: Apparently Apple does not appreciate feed-back on this, because Preview is not listed on the feedback page...

Answer (score 6):

I have the same habit of selecting text as I'm reading. If I change anything by accident (I also tend to shuffle pages) I just push Cmd-Z and the page status goes from *Edited* back to Normal. I just tested this with a file in Dropbox and it didn't fire (i.e. it’s not saving the document if you undo before closing the window).

Not perfect, but it works for me.

Comment: Cmd-Z reverts back the possibly inserted text, but does not remove the text input box, nor does it set the status back to Normal for me. Also, the Edit->Undo menu is greyed out.

Comment: @fishinear: If you first unselect the text box (by clicking outside it (and hoping you don't create a new text box by that)) the undo should work as described.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is largely caused by Apple's change to the Document model introduced in Lion, with changes to the document being auto-saved. While this behaviour is desirable in, say, a Word processor, it's not so desirable in an app like Preview, which is often used for Viewing originals that should not be edited.

You can turn off Apple's Auto-save in Preview with the following Terminal command:

```
defaults write -app 'Preview' ApplePersistence -bool no
```

As a result, if you accidentally click on the document and create a Text Annotation, the change will not be saved unless you manually save the document.

EDIT: This no longer seems to work in Mojave and upwards. If you truly want a read-only PDF viewer (or one that requires explicit saves), you may need to use another application.

Answer (score -2):

Go under **File**->**Print**, choose **Save as PDF** in the drop-down PDF menu in the **lower left** corner of the dialog box. Works like a charm.

Comment: How does this disable editing?

Comment: Saved file is going to be uneditable. Try it, when that worked please get back your downvote.

Comment: @alwaysprep This answer doesn't work.  I think you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: that's very simple & that's what I was looking for tks.

Comment: This WORKS for me!!!